# What do all the perk machines do and which perks should I have?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

After about round ten, I can get Pack-a-punched weapons and elemental upgrades easily, but I have no idea what I can do regarding perks. I just want to be able to get rid of those zombies and train them around more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perk machines are for the most part the same as previous Treyarch Call of Duties.  They are renamed, but for clarity, the *italicized* names are what they were called in previous Call of Duties (and also sums up what they do for the most part).  The **bold** names are what they are called in Infinite Warfare.  If there isn't an italicized name, then they are a new machine.

- **Up n Atoms**: *Quick Revive.*  In multiplayer, you revive other players faster if they are down.  In single player, it will automatically revive yourself if you go down and be consumed.
- **Tuff Enuff**:  *Juggernaut*.  You can take more hits before going down.
- **Quickies**: *Speed Cola*.  You reload your weapons faster and can repair windows much faster.
- **Racin' Stripes**: *Stamin-Up*.  Allows you to sprint faster.
- **Slappy Taffee**: Increases your melee damage and adds a knockback effect to your melee.
- **Bombstoppers**: *PHD Flopper*.  You are immune to your own explosion damage weapons and grenades.
- **Trailerblazers**: When you slide, you leave behind a trail of fire.
- **Bang Bangs**: *Double Tap*. You fire two bullets at once.
- **Mule Munchies:** *Mule Kick.*  Allows you to carry a third weapon.
- **Blue Bolts:** *Electric Cherry.* When you reload, you emit and electrical field around you that shocks nearby zombies.

<sub>[(Source)](https://www.primagames.com/games/call-duty-infinite-warfare/tips/all-perk-machine-locations-zombies-spaceland)</sub>

It's up to you what perks you want.  But Tuff Enuff is almost always a must for later rounds.  Bombstoppers is very good on the Spaceland map, since if you upgrade the pistol you start with, it becomes the familiar Mustang and Sally combo (though also renamed).  This upgraded gun shoots essentially grenades that explode on contact.  This gun is extremely handy when attempting to do the [Easter Egg](http://gameranx.com/features/id/80563/article/infinite-warfare-zombies-in-spaceland-the-complete-easter-egg-guide/) on this map when you have to defend the satellite dishes.

You can also check out [the Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Candy_Perk) for more about the perks.

Comment: Just a note, Blue Bolts used to be known as Electric Cherry in some maps. Good summary though

Comment: @Dpeif yup, though I don't think there was a dedicated machine for that perk on all the maps.  You could get it via gobble gum or the Random Perk machine maker thing I believe.